# How to authorize user to open certain page if he has any roles using spatie Laravel

Tags: laravel

I only want users who have been given any roles or permissions to access the home page, I already redirect the user after login to another page (profile page), but I want to block access to the home page by showing 403 error page if the user tries to access it using the direct URL.

I created a helper function in Laravel to check for this

```php
function checkAnyRoles() {
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    
    $userModel = User::where('id',$user_id)->first();
    $userRoles = $userModel->getRoleNames()->all();

    if (count($userRoles) != 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

it works fine in the blade, but in middlewares I couldn't figure out how to do this.

I'm using Laravel 10.0 with spatie 2.0.

To figure out how to use custom condition in middleware of spatie packgage.

Comment: is there a reason just `return Auth::user()->roles->isNotEmpty();` wouldn't work?